# Trying to put a background colour under my menu, z-index problems

Tags: css

I am trying to place a 100px background under my menu but I don't want it in the containing element of the menu. So I've created a separate div called `#topbar` that's 100px wide and I've given it a absolute position and then a z-index to place it on top of my menu.

```
#topbar {     
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #666;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 15000;
    }
```

However I want it to be under my menu, I lower the z-index of `#topbar` but then the menu overlays it completely despite me trying to make it transparent. The header class is called `fusion-header-wrapper`

It's a little hard to place the code for all of this as it's a wordpress template... Website located here so you can fiddle with it: http://rwc.brightonpacific.com.au/

Ideally I'd have preferred to just place a background color in the element of the menu, but the menu's height is too much and I don't believe you can position where you want a background color to start from.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you include the html and css of that menu?

Comment: It's a little hard. As it's wordpress. Was hoping people could just inspect the elements, but I can try

Comment: Your avada-126.css file is applying a background color to `.fusion-header`. You can override this by either using `.fusion-header{background-color:transparent !important}` or `.fusion-header-v7 .fusion-header{background-color:transparent}`. Then set your `#topbar` back to having a `z-index` below that of the header

Comment: That did it! I was playing with doing that and it wasn't working! Thank you. If you could post it as an answer so I can label it correct :)